# ISearch - Paste - text in mini buffer is not same

Tags: isearch

Windows 10, Emacs 25

1. Select text
   [image]
2. second word is upper case.
3. Press `C-s`
4. Paste text

[image]
Why whole text is lower case in mini buffer?

Answer (score 2):

isearch is *case-insensitive* by default, and this behaviour is connected to that.

Typing <kbd>M-c</kbd> while isearching calls `isearch-toggle-case-fold` which enables you to switch to a case-sensitive search, at which point you'll observe that your search string will retain its mixed-case when you paste it into the minibuffer.

The manual says:

> Normally, when the search is case-insensitive, text yanked into the
>   search string is converted to lower case, so that the search remains
>   case-insensitive (*note case folding: Lax Search.).  However, if the
>   value of the variable ‘search-upper-case’ (*note search-upper-case: Lax
>   Search.) is other than ‘not-yanks’, that disables this down-casing.

See:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Isearch Yank`
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Lax Search`
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `search-upper-case`

Answer (score 0):

If you select the text and paste it while the pointer is still in the scratch buffer ( in your example) the text is copied all lower case.

This is corrected by moving the pointer to the minibuffer like so: copy-region: `M-w`, calling I-serach: `C-s` or `M-x I-search-forward` ,moving the pointer to the mini buffer: `C-x o`, mouse click, or whatever method you use, and yank `C-y`.

The text will be copied correctly.

Comment: Alt-e is a quick way to edit the isearch string.